# Does Kafka Mirror Maker 1 have auto partition discovery?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Note: Not talking about mirror maker2.

I'd like the replicate a topic from source cluster to the target kafka cluster. Let's say I'm gonna replicate topic that has 32 partitions.

Deploying: topic, 32 partitions => 32 consumers

So, the number of partitions of the source topic changed to the 48 in the source system.

In that case, is kafka mirror maker1 going to detect new added partitions (new 16 partitions) automatically without re-deploying the kafka mirror maker1 application again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will detect partition changes, yes, as any consumer does, and start consuming them upon the next metadata update.

However, it'll not replicate the partition change to increase the destination topic partitions; it'll (re)partition the data into  however many partitions exist in the destination topic

Comment: "it'll not replicate the partition change". Does this mean it won't read the data from newly added partitions? At the end of the day, I'm gonna create topic with specifiec number of partitions on the target kafka, so it doesn't matter for me if it will also read data from newly added partitions.

Comment: I did not say that. I said it would not increase the partition size of the destination topic

Comment: Okay, in that case it doesn't matter. I can increase the partitions manually in the destination topic. Thank you much!